# Why can't my program find my text file I am trying to scan?

Tags: java

I tried to put the file in as many places as I could to just see if any of them would work. I also tried to use the direct path but that also didn't work. I have a mac and am wondering if that is messing something up.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String nextString=null;
    PopularName nextName;
    String[] info=new String[5];
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("LastNames.txt"));
```

...

Comment: Without showing the codes, it is highly impossible to tell where the bug is

Comment: With no details at all how do you expect anyone to help?

Comment: post the actual code and not the image also add a try catch to your code

Comment: Post text, not images.

Comment: It's probably trying to look in the same directory but it is one directory up.

Comment: Bottom line is that if the program can't find the file then it's not looking in the right spot.

Comment: put it our of `/src/` (in main project folder)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but the `FileReader` does also have a `FileReader(String)` constructor.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch FileReader has a constructor that accepts file path

Comment: My mistake; `FileNotFoundException` is a **checked** exception; and OP isn't handling (or re-throwing) it.

Comment: learn exception handling

Comment: I did handle it but when I ran it it still couldn't find the file

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

You can get the current root directory of the project.
So if you put a file there you can read is like this:

```
new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/LastNames.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more errors in your code:

1. Scanner takes as argument File (FileReader makes no sense here),
2. You are not taking care about exceptions -> either try-catch block or your method must throw it to upper level - see working example below.

The path to file should be relative to the root of project of absolute.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(inFile.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I changed it however when I run it it still can't find the file.

Comment: Then try to use the absolute path of the file. That should would - or there may be issues with file permissions...